# Opera margin direction in LTR documents

Tags: html, css, margin, opera

Opera has a strange behavior when it comes to RTL documents. Take this simple grid system for example:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body dir="rtl">
        <div class="grid-row">
            <div class="col-1"></div>
            <div class="col-1"></div>
            <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-row">
            <div class="col-1"></div>
            <div class="col-1"></div>
            <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid-row {
    font-size:0;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    width: 210px;
}
.col-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.col-1:last-child {margin-left:0;}
```

If you view [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/db49bwqw/) in any browser other than Opera, it displays perfectly fine. It seems that Opera is changing the margin direction for RTL documents. How can this be fixed?

I know that Opera has a very small market share, but I would still like my website to display properly in it.

**NOTE**: I cannot change the direction of the document.

**EDIT**: I'm using Opera v12.16 for Mac OS X

Comment: Which version of opera? I just compared Opera with Chrome and they were the same

Comment: In any case try using the `direction` css property... Something like `body { direction:rtl; }`

Comment: @Danield It is Opera v12.16 for Mac OS X (currently the latest version)

Comment: Oh Ok. You should probably note that in your question, because this is the pre-blink opera version.... nowadays opera generally renders like Chrome

Comment: what's pre-blink? I had the same behavior on a previous version

Comment: [Blink](http://www.chromium.org/blink) is opera's new rendering engine